# How to assign a tooltip at a macro button added by customize ribbon in ms excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, vba, macros

I want to assign a tooltip to a macro button added by me by customizing ribbon in options at file tab in MS Excel.

You can see this snapshot for understanding that where and how I want the tooltip.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On your Excel document click:

File --> Options --> Quick Access Toolbar

On the drop down list select Macros.

[image]

You should see your macro on both the right and left side of the screen.

From there you can click modify and type the text in the text box (you can also assign an image to your macro). Click okay.

Not sure if there's a time limit you can set for how long the tooltip appears on the screen. But the tooltip will stay on the screen until you've moved the cursor away from the macro.

Comment: Dear @zain.ali, thanks for your reply. Sir I do not want to add the macro button in quick access toolbar as it sets the macro button on top left corner of excel sheet. I want this macro button should be shown on home tab. So is there any way to show tooltip when mouse pointer is hovered over it in home tab.